# same comparison of different numeric types

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compare, c++17, variant

I have two variants of several numeric types that I'd like to compare.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <variant>

using Value = std::variant< uint64_t, int64_t, bool, float, double>;

bool compare(Value l, Value r){
    return std::visit([](auto v1,auto v2){return v1<v2;},l,r);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ULCfVk

On msvc this causes warnings however.

Is this safe? (aka gives the expected results during all circumstances)

If not how can it be accomplished safely?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this safe?

Depends on what you consider "safe". Your code does not involve undefined behavior or such things, but it can definitely lead to unexpected results. Example:

```
Value v1 = std::int64_t{std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::min()};
Value v2 = std::uint64_t{42};

// Isn't v1 < v2? This assertion will fire...
assert(compare(v1, v2));
```

The issue here is that your catch-all visitor (the generic lambda) will not distinguish between types and happily compares a signed integral value with an unsigned one. The former is converted to the latter, yielding a large value and the comparison returns true.

> If not how can it be accomplished safely?

You can add additional overloads to the visitor function object. Have a look at the `overloaded` machinery [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit). This way, you do distinguish between the type that the variant holds whenever the comparison requires it to do the right thing (i.e., return an expectable result).